# help!! why is my echo not printing? :"(

Tags: php, echo

I am coding in php. I tried debugging to see if the value is null.

Here is my code:

```
echo if (isset($_Post[porduct]));
```

It doesn't work, does anyone know why??

Comment: You are trying to echo an if statement. That is not going to work. Maybe something like `echo (isset($_POST[porduct])) ? 'true' : 'false';`? Also, `$_Post` should be uppercase, like so `$_POST;`

Comment: Friend read manuals , check how the construct is made . See how the construct properly - It is  IF SOMETHING THEN DO  SOMETHIG sounds correct and not english like statement echo something if something !This is not rocket science - and PHP is not stupid but users are !! :)

Comment: I would say put it in double quote `echo "if (isset($_Post[porduct]));"` and you will get result

Comment: @xxxkellyxxx If by stupid you mean "When I don't follow the manual, it doesn't work" then yes, PHP is stupid.

Comment: @Shakti No, that will just print `if (isset()));`

Comment: @Blowski: that at least print something and he want to print something

Comment: Clearly PHP is stupid for not allowing people to do stupid things

Comment: php not doing what i want whyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

Comment: @xxx: Because you don't know how to ride PHPPPPPPPPPPPPPP.

Comment: @SQueryL this proves that I can visit StackOverflow to have an assured hearty laugh. Thanks for pointing it out, in such a hilarious way :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`if (isset($_Post[porduct]))` doesn't actually return anything so there's nothing to echo. Did you mean instead:

```
if (isset($_Post[porduct])) echo "is set"; //or any other message
```

Comment: It's actually a syntax error. `if` is not an expression.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you meant:

```
if(isset($_POST['product']))
 echo "Product = ".$_POST['product']."\r\n";
else
 echo "Product not set!\r\n";
```

Please, pay attention to the ' (quotes) around the word *product* and the case of the $_POST variable. If you omit the quotes (single,',or double, ") around *product*, you'll get a PHP notice because *product* (without quotes) would be interpreted as a constant (which could lead to unexpected results), and only if it was not found as a constant, PHP would fall back to the corresponding string, that is, 'product'.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it that way. `if` returns nothing, so it will probably yield a parse error.

You'll to do it another way. Like:

```
if (isset($_Post[porduct]))
    echo 'is set';
else
    echo 'isn\'t set';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it:

```
echo isset($_POST['product'])? 'YES' : 'NO';
```